# .htaccess simple mod_rewrite sends 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've created an *.htaccess* file in a shared server, inside a folder called *API* that is a child of the root folder.

I've placed the following simple code inside the file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /API/ # also tested with / alone (edit) also tested removing-it

RewriteRule ^/API/(\d+)*$ /API/index.php?i=$1
```

My intentions is to turn `/API/{var}` into `/API/index.php?i={var}`, but the trick ain't working at all. What can be causing the issue, since every query var I sends me into **404**.

What can be causing the problem? Where should I start debugging?

**Edit:**
After several failed attempts I'm gonna try using [the FastRoute php library](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) as an alternative, since this .htaccess issue seems unresolvable.

Thanks [Félix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576767/f%C3%A9lix-gagnon-grenier) for all the help in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the leading slash **/**  and **API** in your rewrite pattern, Remove them from there

Try :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /API/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ /API/index.php?i=$1 [NC,L]
```